# Wildcard email gateway / software / api

Tags: api, email, google-apps, gateway

is there any existing software (web based application), which allows to have all incoming emails (to wildcard email *@domain.com) to be posted via REST API to my web application?

The same thing Tumblr or Posterous does, it assigns you an email (for example trrehret3453@tumblr.com) where you can send text and pictures and it automatically posts it to your blog, I need exactly the same.

Maybe there's a mail server which can do that? I'm running Debian Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this service: http://www.emailyak.com, they provide REST API for incoming emails.